# Get touchesBegan on a subview (UIWebView)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I've an UIWebView which is added as a subview in a UIview and I would like to detect when this UIWebView is touched but touchesBegan just don't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: How about showing the relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Subclass UIWebView in your code and then implement touchesBegan in your class.
2. Add the subclassed webview as a subview of your UIView.
3. Call super in the subclassed UIWebView

   ```
   - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
   {
       [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing and waiting for touchesBegan won't help you, as it won't get called.
I subclassed `UIWebView` and just "leeched" onto its gesture recognizers in subviews 2 levels deep (you could go recursively but thats enough for iOS6-7).
Then you can do whatever you want with the touch location and gesture recognizer's state.

```
for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in view.gestureRecognizers) {
        [recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:)];
    }
    for (UIView* sview in view.subviews) {
        for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in sview.gestureRecognizers) {
            [recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5

**subview.swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

If you're unsure if you should call `super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)`, refer to the doc [discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan).

**superview.swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // handle
}
```