# iOS subview not forwarding touches.

Tags: ios, subview, touches

I have tried this a few different ways but none of them seem to work. I have a UIView subclass that has some buttons in it. I tried adding the subview to my ViewControllers however it will not respond to touches unless I set it to "initWithFrame:self.view.frame" but then it takes All of the touches and does not pass them to the view controller. I also tried adding it directly to the window so it's on top of all of the view however I have the same issue, either it will not accept touches or it takes them all.

here is how I add it when it takes all touches for itself and does not pass them on.

```
ControlView *cont = [[ControlView alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
[self.window addSubview:cont];
```

I'm so confused as to how to fix this and I have a lot more important tasks to work on but I have been stuck for two days with this stupid subview/touch issue.

Comment: It's similar to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9524797/1054184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you handling touches?  UIGestureRecognizer?

You should make sure that your uiview subclass has userInteractionEnabled = YES.  That's the default but maybe it got turned off somewhere along the line.

Comment: I'm not handling touches, or rather I have not added any code except the functionality that usually comes with UIViewControllers etc. The only thing I have is a gesture recognizer in my subview that like everything else in the subview either does not get touches or gets all of the touches depending on how I add it to the viewcontroller.